# Assign Tab to switch input method

Tags: shortcut, keybindings, input-source

I want to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the previously-used input source, and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> as the usual tab function.

As a Chinese language user, the key combination I use the most is <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, which selects the previous input source. Since I only have two keyboards enabled, selecting the previous input source is the same thing as toggling between them. For every non-English user, this switch is frequent.

To make it easier, I want to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch input sources. 
Following this, a <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> sounds like a good idea to perform the normal function of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

However, System Preferences (as I tried it) only allows the user to set the switch as a combination starting with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ Control</kbd>. 
Is my request unreasonable? Or can it be done?

Comment: Have you tried https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

Comment: Thank you @timothymh, your edit is succinct. Btw, I think my reference to Vim is relevant, because it gets more cumbersome to toggle input source AND to leave/enter input mode --- But it's enough that I mention this in this comment.

Comment: @Bowen Yes, I have heard Karabiner. A notice says Sierra is not supported on the very page you cited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found Karabiner Elements works for Sierra, and I am very satisfied now.

Previously, Karabiner is out of order in Sierra. 
Indeed, Sierra starts to offer custom remaps among those of <kbd>⇪Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>^Control</kbd>, <kbd>⌥Option</kbd>, and <kbd>⌘Command</kbd>, with System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier keys. 
Still, I cannot use any of them to switch input source with System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources.

There has been several months, and today I visited [Karabiner's homepage](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) again. 
They say they produced a [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements) for Sierra, but I cannot compile myself, though had not closely studied the error message. 
Besides, fortunately there is a [latest compiled image](https://pqrs.org/latest/karabiner-elements-latest.dmg). 
The link is not anywhere obvious on their homepage, but I found it in another forum discussion, so I hope more people seeing this (my post) can find this image.

Karabiner Elements works fine, as far as I see, for simple assignment of keys — i.e. to force the physical key `X`'s signal to be interpreted as key `Y`'s function. 
This is my setting. 
Physical <kbd>⇪Caps Lock</kbd> now performs the function of <kbd>Esc</kbd>, 
and <kbd>Esc</kbd> that of <kbd>`</kbd>, 
and <kbd>`</kbd> that of <kbd>↹Tab</kbd> , 
and <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> that of <kbd>F4</kbd> (or something else), 
and <kbd>F4</kbd> that of <kbd>⇪Caps Lock</kbd>. 
Then I set <kbd>F4</kbd> to switch to the previously-used input source. 
I am proud of my setting. Vim users for non-Latin family language will save considerable effort with this!